# C++ - Why can you return a reference to a "stack object"

Tags: c++

I don't understand how this code works:

```
class AAA {
public:
    short a, b;
};

AAA &getRef() {
    AAA aaa = {2, 6};
    return aaa;
} // 'aaa' is destroyed here right?

int main() {
    AAA &ref = getRef();
    cout << ref.a << ", " << ref.b << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't there be an error trying to access `ref.a` and `ref.b`? When I use pointers, I don't get an error either. I mean,this prints "2, 6" **every single time**.

EDIT: Is it because the memory is still set to those numbers?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, not just an error.

Comment: @chris Except for the fact that I keep getting the same results

Comment: @Susan So what? It's still undef behaviour. It might blow up next time. Or worse, once you write code that is deployed on your company's customers' systems.

Comment: @SusanYanders: Getting the same results is one possible behavior when you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @us2012 The code is obviously working when it shouldn't!

Comment: @Susan Who says it shouldn't?! It's called undefined behaviour because you can't know what will happen. All you know is that it's possible that it blows up. And that's why you shouldn't do it.

Comment: There is a related thread with a nice disassembly and explanation over here: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13808/

Comment: Stack-allocated objects are destroyed at the end of their respective scopes. Trying to access them afterwards is undefined behavior. Dynamically-allocated objects are on the heap and won't be destroyed until the user calls `delete`.

Comment: Try calling a second method (with lots of local variables, all initialized to zero) between that first method and the output. You're likely (but strictly, not guaranteed) to find that suddenly you don't get those results. The reason for this undefined behaviour isn't some kind of arbitrary randomness to annoy you, it results from the way compilers use the processor stack. There may be a return-value optimisation issue in this case - I always forget the rules for that.

Comment: Please don't remove the content of your post because of the answers.

Comment: If you looked at the compiler output (asm), I suspect it's copying `aaa` into `ref` when `getRef` returns. (don't count on the compiler always doing that.)

Comment: @RickyBeam I think you have some misconceptions about how references work.

Comment: @SusanYanders If you want to understand what might actually be going on here, you need to understand how the stack works. Possible keywords that will lead you to relevant tutorials: stack, stack frame, calling convention. This is a worthwhile exercise, but don't get into the habit of trying to explain instances of undefined behaviour - it's usually not productive to do so.

Comment: This question has been asked hundreds of times here. **Undefined behaviour does not mean you get an error!** See ["Somebody told me that in basketball you can't hold the ball and run. I got a basketball and tried it and it worked just fine. He obviously didn't understand basketball."](http://c-faq.com/ansi/experiment.html) and other links at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/undefined-behavior/info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: @us2012, perhaps, but a) he's returning an object not a ref to `aaa`, and b) this is uncharted compiler waters. (looking at what g++ 4.4.5 generates, it's even simpler... `aaa` never exists, `ref` from `main` is populated directly. and btw, it emits a warning.)

Comment: @RickyBeam Your point (a) isn't correct, this function *does* return a reference.

Comment: @us2012, please take a minute to look at your compiler output and tell me if it's returning anything or simply filling in `ref` on the stack.

Comment: @Ricky [Godbolt sample](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22source%22%3A%22class%20A%7B%5Cnpublic%3A%5Cn%20%20%20%20int%20a%2C%20b%3B%5Cn%7D%3B%5Cn%5CnA%20%26g()%20%7BA%20a%20%3D%20%7B2%2C%206%7D%3B%20return%20a%3B%7D%20%5Cn%5Cnint%20main()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20A%20%26r%20%3D%20g()%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%200%3B%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22%2Fusr%2Fbin%2Fg%2B%2B-4.8%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O0%22%7D%5D%7D)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It "works" because the memory for `aaa` hasn't been overwritten when the function returns. If you modify the `AAA` class to have a destructor that modifies `a` and `b`, or if you use some code that writes to the stack, it will almost certainly overwrite the values.

Returning a reference to a local variable is defined by the C++ standard as a "undefined behaviour". The standard often does this in cases where it may, for example, be difficult to determine that the value is indeed stack-based.

For example, consider:

```
class BBB
{
   AAA& x;
  public:
   BBB(AAA& a) : x(a) {}
   AAA& getX() { return x; }
};

AAA& getReg()
{
   AAA aaa = { 2, 6}
   BBB bbb(aaa);
   return bbb.getX();
}
```

Most modern compilers will issue a warning for the scenario you have, and some may also give a warning for the code I just wrote. But it's almost certainly possible to come up with some more convoluted case for where it's NOT possible to diagnose this "error".

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this is illegal code that invokes undefined behaviour, but it is not flagged as error by the compiler (although it might if more compiler diagnostics are enabled).

It happens to work by accident, presumably because the memory location where the object is created is not re-used for anything else, and is not cleared or overwritten, so you are just "lucky" that the values, once put there, remain.

Comment: you didnt even answer my question. i wanted to know why the memory was still allocated when it went out of scope.

Comment: @SusanYanders He did answer, in a way. The memory is not "still allocated". It was momentarily until the `return aaa`, not anymore. The memory is still impregnated with the values it had when it *was* allocated, though. Reason being that "releasing" memory simply means that the area of memory (number of bytes) that was temporarily reserved to some usage is not reserved anymore. And until another part of your program (or the system or...) re-reserves it and writes in it, the values you put there initially remain as is.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want "proof" that it can fail. Maybe try:

```
int main() {
    AAA &ref = getRef();
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    cout << ref.a << ", " << ref.b << endl;
}
```

also, you should enable and pay attention to your compiler's warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `short`s with a user-defined type with a complicated destructor (like `string`), and you will probably see this crash. Because the memory has been reclaimed, but the old value is still sitting there, you can (sometimes) see the value of built-in types (like `int`, `short`, etc.) even after destruction.

[[Sample Code]](https://ideone.com/moRCOP)

Comment: You can sometimes see the value of non-built-in types too. There's no reason it has to crash just because of a user-defined destructor.

Comment: In my experience, you're a lot more likely to crash dereferencing deleted pointers than looking at reclaimed stack memory. Since it's undefined, your experiences almost certainly differ. :D